FEM for Poisson equation using C1 continuous element
When utilizing the standard Bubnov-Galerkin method and $C^1$ continuous element (such as Argyris, Bell, and HCT) on the Poisson equation \begin{align} \nabla^2u=-f \text{ in } \Omega \\ u=g \text{ on } \Gamma \end{align} or other linear second-order PDEs, is it necessary to integrate by parts?
If not, then using the Nitsche's method to weakly impose the Dirichlet boundary conditions and integrate by parts, there is \begin{align} \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v - \int_{\Gamma}v \nabla u \cdot \pmb{n} - \int_{\Gamma} (u-g) \nabla v \cdot \pmb{n} + \beta\int_{\Gamma} (u-g) v = \int_{\Omega}fv \end{align}
But now dropping the initegration by parts, is the weak form (where the stiffness matrix is not symmetirc and the consistent term vanishes) \begin{align} \int_{\Omega} v{\nabla}^2 u + \beta\int_{\Gamma} v (u-g) = \int_{\Omega}fv \end{align} still valid?

Wouldn't the resulting matrix be exactly the same if you compare
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla v \cdot \nabla u - \int_{\Gamma} \underbrace{v}0 \partial_n u = \int{\Omega} vf$$
and
$$-\int_{\Omega} v\Delta u = \int_{\Omega} vf$$
and you impose the Dirichlet conditions strongly? In the first case you would have $W_{ij} = \int_{\Omega} \nabla \phi_i \cdot \nabla \phi_j$ while in the latter case you would have $W_{ij} = -\int_{\Omega} \phi_i \Delta \phi_j$, but those two integrals are equal. Typically Argyris and Bell are used for the biharmonic equation though.

$C^1$ elements are not complete in $H^1$, and so you should not expect them to converge for the Laplace equation.

@WolfgangBangerth How could $C^1$ elements be used for biharmonic equations if they are not complete in $H^1$?

@lightxbulb Sorry for my poor knowledge of FEM theory, I'm not sure they are equal after discretization. Because the $-\int_{\Omega} v\Delta u = \int_{\Omega} vf$ requires $u$ to have square-integrable first derivatives while $\int_{\Omega} \nabla v \cdot \nabla u - \int_{\Gamma} v \partial_n u = \int_{\Omega} vf$ only needs $u$ in $H^1$. I just think the form without integration by parts is also fine if I use the $C^1$ element. Am I right?

@zz They are complete in $H^2$, a smaller space than $H^1$.

@WolfgangBangerth You are right, I mistake about their relation. But the Laplacian is a second-order operator, so why must I require the finite element space to be $H^1$? Is there any theorem for this statement?

The solutions of the Laplace equation happen to be in $H^1$, not $H^2$. That's because if you look at the weak formulation, all you need is one (weak) derivative, not two.

When we write $-\Delta u(\Omega)= f(\Omega)$ and $u(\partial\Omega) = g(\partial\Omega)$ and say that we are looking for a weak solution, we really mean that we are looking for a solution of $\int \nabla v \cdot \nabla u = \int vf$, so second derivatives and the classical Laplacian may not even be defined. See this for more details: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/21750/34261
A Poisson eq. weak solution is in $H^1$, a strong solution is in $H^2$, and a classical solution is in $C^2$. I think Bangerth is referring to a weak solution, but you do not necessarily have to need a weak solution.

If you just want higher consistency $O(h^p)$ for the weak Poisson equation, you can increase the polynomial degree, but keep them $C^0$ on the elements boundaries (this also happens to be much simpler than working with Argyris, Bell, or whatever). Argyris and Bell would make sense if you're either looking for a strong solution of the Poisson equation or a weak solution of the biharmonic equation. You could of course also consider non-conforming elements, e.g. Morley for biharmonic, or even just $P_1$ with a squared stiffness matrix.

@lightxbulb Yes, true. But in general, while you are guaranteed that there is a unique weak solution, in many situations the Laplace equation does not have a strong or classical solution.

With C1 elements and if exact solution is only H1, will we not observe any convergence at all, or does it converge at some sub-optimal rate ?

I don't think you can just drop the term $\int_{\partial\Omega} (u-g)\partial_n v$ if you want to use  Nitsche's method. Granted
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla  v \cdot \nabla u - \int_{\Omega} v \partial_n u = -\int_{\Omega} v \Delta u$$
but I don't see how that helps.

Application of Argyris to the Poisson Equation
Consider the Poisson equation $-\Delta u = f$. It's strong and weak form are given as follows:
\begin{align*}
-\int_{\Omega}v\Delta u &= \int_{\Omega} vf, \tag{1}\\
\int_{\Omega} \nabla v \cdot \nabla u - \int_{\partial\Omega} v\partial_n u &= \int_{\Omega} vf. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
An Argyris element has $21$ degrees of freedom: pointwise value $\delta_{v_i}$ at each vertex (3 values), the first derivatives at each vertex $\delta_{v_i}\circ\partial_{x}$ and $\delta_{v_i} \circ\partial_y$ (6 values), the normal
derivatives at the edge midpoints $\delta_{v_i}\circ\partial_{n_i}$ (3 values), the second derivatives at the vertices $\delta_{v_i} \circ \partial_{xx}$, $\delta_{v_i} \circ \partial_{xy}$, $\delta_{v_i} \circ \partial_{yy}$ (9 values). The $21$ degrees of freedom uniquely determine the $5$-th degree polynomial on the triangle.
Suppose you use homogeneous Neumann conditions, or Dirichlet conditions, then either $\partial_n u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$ or $v|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$, which makes the boundary integral zero. Then you can use either of the two formulations to compute the stiffness matrix:
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla \varphi_i \cdot \nabla \varphi_j = W_{ij} = -\int_{\Omega}\varphi_i \Delta \varphi_j.$$
Now, remember how you typically have to posprocess the problem even with $P_1$ elements for $u|_{\partial\Omega} = g$:
$$Wu = f \iff \begin{bmatrix} W_{II} & W_{IB} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u_I \\ u_B \end{bmatrix} = f \iff W_{II}u_I = f - W_{IB}g,$$
where $I$ refers to the set of interior indices, and $B$ refers to the set of boundary indices.
On the other hand, suppose that $\partial_n u|_{\partial\Omega} = h$. If you use the formulation:
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla v \cdot \nabla u - \int_{\partial\Omega} v\partial_n u = \int_{\Omega} vf,$$
you do not need to do much except replace $\partial_n u$ with $h$ in the above. Now suppose you use:
$$-\int_{\Omega}v\Delta u = \int_{\Omega} vf, \quad W_{ij} = -\int_{\Omega}\varphi_i \Delta \varphi_j$$
You would have to postprocess your matrix in a similar manner as for the essential conditions:
$$
Wr = f \iff \begin{bmatrix} W_{II} & W_{IB} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
r_I \\ r_B \end{bmatrix} = f \iff 
W_{II} r_I = f - W_{IB} h.
$$
Here $r$ contains the values at the vertices, gradients at the vertices, second derivatives at the vertices, and the normal derivatives at the midpoints. The set of indices $B$ would now contain the indices corresponding to normal derivatives at the midpoints on the boundary, while $I$ is everything else. So the $\int_{\Omega} v\Delta u$ makes the boundary integral implicit. In an implementation I would probably opt for $\int_{\Omega} \nabla v \cdot \nabla u$ so I wouldn't have to postprocess my $W$ even for the case of Neumann boundary conditions.

Application to the bi-Laplacian Setting
The main application of Argyris is really the biharmonic equation $\Delta^2 u = f$. The weak form of the latter is:
$$\int_{\Omega}vf = \int_{\Omega} v\Delta^2 u = \int_{\Omega}\Delta v \Delta u 
+ \int_{\partial\Omega} v\partial_n \Delta u - \int_{\partial\Omega} \partial_nv \Delta u.$$
For the Poisson equation the essential/Dirichlet condition was $u|_{\partial\Omega} = g$ and the natural/Neumann one was $\partial_n u|_{\partial\Omega} = h$. For the biharmonic equation the essential/Dirichlet conditions are: $u|_{\partial\Omega} = g_1$, $\partial_n u|_{\partial\Omega} = g_2$, while the natural/Neumann ones are $\partial^2_{n}u|_{\partial\Omega} = h_1$ and $\partial^3_n u|_{\partial\Omega} = h_2$. You can also have Navier conditions $u|_{\partial\Omega} = g_1$ and $\Delta u|_{\partial\Omega} =  h_1$, or even $\partial_n u|_{\partial\Omega} = g_2$ and $\partial_n \Delta u|_{\partial\Omega} = h_2$.
Argyris is the most flexible element for biharmonic in terms of how BCs are handled, as it can explicitly prescribe conditions of the form $\partial_n u|_{\partial\Omega} = g_2$ as well as $\Delta u|_{\partial\Omega} = h_1$, since it has normal derivatives on the boundary and second derivatives at the vertices. In contrast, the Bell element cannot prescribe normal derivatives on the boundary explicitly, as it intentionally has the normal derivatives removed. But it can be easily applied to the case of natural boundary conditions or Navier boundary conditions. The Morley element can be applied for the case of Dirichlet conditions, (but Morley is non-conforming, on the other hand it has only 6 degrees of freedom and is quadratic instead of quintic).
Finally, if you have the $u, \Delta u$ or $\partial_n u, \partial_n\Delta u$ conditions you could even just use $P_r$ elements on the coupled problems (but again, this is non-conforming):
\begin{align*}
\Delta^2 u &= f, \quad u|_{\partial\Omega} = g_1, \quad \Delta u|_{\partial\Omega} = h_1 \implies \Delta u = w, \quad \Delta w = f, \quad u|_{\partial\Omega} = g_1, \quad w|_{\partial\Omega} = h_1, \\
\Delta^2 u &= f, \quad \partial_nu|_{\partial\Omega} = g_2, \quad \partial_n\Delta u|_{\partial\Omega} = h_2 \implies \Delta u = w, \quad \Delta w = f, \quad \partial_n u|_{\partial\Omega} = g_2, \quad \partial_n w|_{\partial\Omega} = h_2.
\end{align*}
In practice this results in $\Delta^2 \approx W^2$ where $W_{ij} = \int_{\Omega} \nabla \varphi_i \cdot \nabla \varphi_j$. You can build higher order Laplacian powers in this manner out of $P_r$ elements that are just $C^0$, however, the boundary conditions you can readily handle are either Navier or normal derivatives of Navier.
